# Deploy a flask selenium restful app in production

Tags: python, flask, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to deploy a `Flask REST app` that primarily does two tasks:

1. Normal CRUD Operations
2. Using Python `selenium` to scrape web pages and fetch appropriate results (it opens up Chrome and does the ask)

Can someone suggest to me the best way to deploy such an application in production?

Tried Following ways but was unable to successfully achieve the task

**1. AWS Ubuntu:**
used `gunicorn` to deploy the app was able to do successfully deployed but selenium was only able to open a small size window hence unable to give proper result.

**2. AWS Windows Server:**
used `uvicorn` but getting an error application should be ASGI

I understand the above-mentioned errors can be fixed, but not confident enough to host the application in production, so asking for suggestions what should be the correct way to handle a `Flask REST API` app which internally uses `Selenium` .

P.S. Also if more than one request comes at a time when selenium is running with some other task what are the best practices to handle such scenarios

Comment: What do you mean by internal web pages? What do you do with the scraped results? Where are those results shown?

Comment: It was web pages updated the question , I send the scraped result as an API response, the results are shown in an web app which is successfully deployed at other location

Comment: Are there particular reasons to use Selenium and Chrome to scrape the web pages?

Comment: How many users do you have or expect to have? Are the scraping results different for every user? How often does the scraping need to be done?

Comment: How do you trigger the scraping and how it is run?

Comment: Yes the reason to use Selenium and Chrome is to fetch some data from web page which is otherwise not available to me , I am expecting to have maximum 1000 api hits in a day and yes the response for every user is different

Comment: I am facing the same issue, @Navitas28 any luck with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the architecture**

Based on my understanding, you have two systems:

- A that has an API and does web page scraping, and
- B that shows the results of the scraping.

I would implement this so that when the API in system A gets a request to scrape data the request is enqueued in a queue that is handled by a background process. This background process would then run the scraper that would post the results to the system B, as you described above.

The queue would be stored in a database of some kind depending on which background process library you use. You could then be scraping as many requests in parallel as you have workers available for the queue handler.

You could also save the results of the scraping in a cache if you get requests for the same data to not have to scrape it again every time.

**About deployment**

If I understood correctly, the question is mostly about deploying the system A. You could deploy it to basically any platform or cloud provider that supports running a Python/Flask application with background processes.

Otherwise, you can customize everything exactly how you want if you deploy to something like AWS EC2, for example. Using Docker and deploying your system in containers is also an option but maybe a bit more advanced one.

I think you are going to have problems whichever deployment strategy you choose if you are not using a headless browser with Selenium and if you are not using some kind of a queue to handle the incoming scraping requests.

Choosing the platform or cloud provider to deploy to depends also on your budget as there are quite significant differences between them.

**About scraping**

IMHO, Selenium and Chrome (headless, I assume) are quite resource-intensive and can be a slow way to scrape data. There are lighter and faster alternatives, such as Requests and Beautiful Soup or dedicated scraping frameworks for example, unless specific reasons require to use Selenium.

**About queues**

As a queue for background tasks, I would probably choose one of:

- [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) with Redis, or
- [Redis Queue (RQ)](https://python-rq.org/).

Celery is very widely used while Redis Queue is a bit simpler option.

Above, I mentioned Celery + Redis because I would avoid RabbitMQ as Redis is so much simpler to use and manage.

Michael Herman has guides for both options: https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-and-celery/ (Flask + Celery + Redis) and https://testdriven.io/blog/asynchronous-tasks-with-flask-and-redis-queue/ (Flask + RQ). These guides show you how to containerize these parts with Docker, which could benefit you if you are already using Docker. If not, just skip those parts. Also to note is that you want to push the results to another application and not use Redis as the result storage or backend.

Flask also has a guide for how to use Celery with it: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/celery/.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I am new to `python` can you please help me with which queues can be used here are we talking about `Redis` or `rabbit mq` which need their setup, or can be done via some `Python` provided queue and also it would be great if you can guide me to some resource where I can find queue stored in databases and workers picking up queues.

Comment: I updated my answer to include suggestions about task queues.